# symfony2 / doctrine 2 / Mysql : null values saved as empty strings

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a basic symfony2 form where I can set a value for my field.

I've just figured out that null values where saved as empty strings, where I expect an exception to be raised because thenull value is not accepted.

My mapping (within a trait) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;
```

My field :

```
        ->add('name', null, array(
                'label'=>'Nom détaillé',
                'required' => false))
```

Setting required to true and defining assert rules works well but here I'm trying to solve this conversion issue.

If I put a vardumpin the SetName method, I do get a null value which is later saved as an empty string in my database. How can I solve that ?

EDIT : the show create table t

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `isProduct` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `portions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nickname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `shortDescription` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `weight` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `isPrivate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
 `viewCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `parentId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `userId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `createdBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `updatedBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_DD24B40110EE4CEE` (`parentId`),
 KEY `IDX_DD24B40164B64DCC` (`userId`),
 KEY `IDX_DD24B401D3564642` (`createdBy`),
 KEY `IDX_DD24B401E8DE7170` (`updatedBy`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_DD24B40110EE4CEE` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_DD24B40164B64DCC` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_DD24B401D3564642` FOREIGN KEY (`createdBy`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_DD24B401E8DE7170` FOREIGN KEY (`updatedBy`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This is totally clear. The field is not nullable text so null translates to empty string.

Comment: What's the default value? Can you post the `show create table t` output?

Comment: hmm, is that the usual behaviour ? should I not receive an exception ? or how could I have it throw an exception ?

Comment: You can use Doctrine Event hooks and Lifecycle callbacks for such error checking. Read more here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: Or rather a Validator if it's a form field.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to add a strict equivalence check `===` against the variable and then `throw new Exception()` if it's null

Comment: well, sure I can check for that and throw an exception, that's not a problem. i'm more trying to understand if it's the default behaviour (I thought it was note) and if it is the default, how can I have it throw an exception automatically instead of converting autmatically to empty string

Comment: by the way, with the same field for another entity (as I am using a trait), I have an exception when null.

Comment: I see. What does the trait look like? And are both objects that use the trait part of the same lineage?

Comment: Basically I'm thinking there has to be a difference between the save methods on the two objects. We need to find it.